# Angularjs module wide constants best practice

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have several "modules" (aprox. 20) with their own functionality, but all with the same structure. Every "module" is spread over different files. For example the admin "module" is stored in the modules/admin folder and consists of the following files:

```
admin.module.js
admin.routes.js
admin.content.jade
admin.content.controller.js
admin.content.controller.spec.js
admin.sidebartop.jade
admin.sidebar.controller.js
admin.sidebar.controller.spec.js
and many more......
```

All similar files for all modules have the same code structure. 
All code is encapsulated in a iifi.

To prevent errors and make structure reuse easy I need to define some module specific constants and reuse those const in the controllers, route, etc.

**I'm aware of the module.config and constant functionality**. This approach does not do the job because I cannot reuse the same name twice. This means I still have to rewrite some parts of my code while I want to keep it untouched.

```
angular.module('app.foo').constant('CONST', {...})
```

will conflict with

```
angular.module('app.bar').constant('CONST', {...})
```

So I came up with the following solution, this works just fine, but **somehow does not feel as the right approch.**:

All my static configuration is done in the *.module.js file

```
    (function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app.admin', [
        'app.foo',
        'app.bar'
    ]).CONST ={
            module: 'Admin',
            state: 'admin',
            url : '/admin',
            path: 'app/views/modules/admin/',
            title: 'Admin',
            description: 'This is the admin module',
            acl: ['Developer','Administrator'],
            tileGroups: ['Company'],
            icon: 'mif-books',
            badge: 0,
            filters :
                {'rootNodes' :{where: {'Template.value' : 'Admin'} } },
            ready : false
        };
    })();
```

I reuse the configuration in *.routes.js:

```
    (function () {
        'use strict';

        var module =angular.module('app.details');
        var CONST = module.CONST;
        module.run(appRun);

        appRun.$inject = [ 'routerHelper'];
        /* @ngInject */
        function appRun( routerHelper) {
            var states = [{
                state: CONST.state,
                config: {
                    title: CONST.title,
                    url: CONST.url,
                    acl: CONST.acl,
                    templateUrl: CONST.path + CONST.state + '.content.html',
                    controller: CONST.module + 'ContentController',
                    controllerAs: 'vm',
                    ncyBreadcrumb: {
                        label: CONST.module
                    }
                }
            }
            ];
            routerHelper.configureStates(states);
        }
    })();
```

And in all my *.*.controller.js files :

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.admin')
        .controller('AdminContentController', AdminContentController);

    AdminContentController.$inject = ['foo', 'bar'];
    /* @ngInject */
    function DetailsContentController(foo, bar) {
        var vm = this;
        _.extend(vm, CONST); // for re-usage in my jade / html files

        // AND HERE GOES THE ACTUAL CODE
    }
})();
```

The purpose of this approach is to minimize the changes needed in the individual files if something changes "module" wide.

If for example I change the title from 'Admin' to 'Administration', I don't have to change this in all the files that uses the title. Also my spec.js files are automated so my test will keep in tact if I change a setting.

There must be a **less dirty, more angular** way of solving this problem ?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`constant()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#constant):

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('app.admin', [
    'app.foo',
    'app.bar'
]).constant('CONST', {
        module: 'Admin',
        state: 'admin',
        url : '/admin',
        path: 'app/views/modules/admin/',
        title: 'Admin',
        description: 'This is the admin module',
        acl: ['Developer','Administrator'],
        tileGroups: ['Company'],
        icon: 'mif-books',
        badge: 0,
        filters :
            {'rootNodes' :{where: {'Template.value' : 'Admin'} } },
        ready : false
    });
})();
```

Then use it by including `CONST` in the inject. For example:

```
function AdminContentController(foo, bar, CONST) {...}
AdminContentController.$inject = ['foo', 'bar', 'CONST'];
```

Comment: I've tried this, but this does not do the job. This is fine if I had only only 1 module. If I inject CONST in for example in the module foo, I actually inject the values of the CONST defined in admin, not the values defined in foo.

Comment: @marcelde Names in angular are globally unique, so this is intended behaviour. If you want different constants in different modules, give them different names. It won't change how you use them at all because right now you're doing `angular.module('app.foo').CONST` and `angular.module('app.bar').CONST`. Instead, just do `.constant('fooCONST', ...)` and `.constant('barCONST', ...)`.

Comment: Yep, your right. The proposed solution means I have to change the names of the injections in all the dependent files. To keep things readable, I also have to change the names of the injected CONST in the code itself. I have 12 dependent files per "module". 23 modules .... 23*(12+1) results into 299 files to change and aprox. 11960 changes. And there goes my weekend.  All kind of approaches will work. But because of the huge impact, I'm looking for the "best" solution. It would be nice to find a solution that keeps things simple but flexible and automated.